# DRF read_only fields not being ignored when saving

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am using Django 2.2.23 and Django Rest Framework 3.7.7. I have models and serialisers as follows:

```py
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    uid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    order_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(SupplierContact, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    

class SupplierContact(models.Model):
    uid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)


class PurchaseOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='contact.name', default='')

    class Meta:
        model = PurchaseOrder
        fields = ['uid', 'order_number', 'contact_name']
```

Doing

```py
serializer = PurchaseOrderSerializer({'order_number': 1234})
serializer.save()
```

results in `*** ValueError: Cannot assign "{'name': ''}": "PurchaseOrder.contact" must be a "SupplierContact" instance.`

where I would've thought the `read_only=True` on the `contact_name` field would exclude it from saving. What am I missing?

Comment: you are setting read_only=True and then you are setting default=''. which is conflicting.

Comment: remove `default=''` and set `required=False` it will be ignored. if you do not pass contact.

Comment: Figured it out: the `default` kwarg needs to be excluded in the serialiser field declaration.

Comment: @foragerDev yep, thanks. I thought I needed default for when `contact` is `None`. Can you post an answer including why that's not the case?

Comment: For reference https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source says 'When serializing fields with dotted notation, it may be necessary to provide a default value if any object is not present or is empty during attribute traversal.' which apparently is not the case when read_only is True.